# Should I use Device Groups or Topics for a group chat app scenario with Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In a scenario where I'm creating a group chat app where the user can be participating in multiple small group chats and I'm using [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-multiple), should I:

1. Create and send to Device Groups, or
2. should I broadcast to a topic where each group chat becomes a topic the users can subscribe to?

In scenario #1, I imagine I should create a device group for each user and add all of the user's devices to that device group, then send a FCM message to all device groups that are part of the group chat on each new trigger.

Scenario #2 is much easier in that I can have the client device subscribe to a chat room as a topic when they join a group chat - however it wouldn't support a multiple device scenario unless I figure out a way to keep in sync the group chats that the user subscribes to from different devices.

Comment: Hi. FCM is a push notification service that should only help *enrich* user experience through notifications. For a chat app, it is advisable to make use of [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) instead. Where a scenario could be users in the same *room* listen to the same database. There's actually a [Firebase Code Lab here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#0) that you might find useful. :)

Comment: I already have a realtime database set up - but I need the push notifications to let them know that there is a new message

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey,  what did you end up doing?  Also for topics from device to device should we wait 1 day until a notification can be sent from one device to another?

Comment: I actually ended up keeping track of all device tokens of a user and sending messages out to each device token.  I didn't end up using device tokens.  As for waiting one day - I'm not sure what use case that is since I don't have a device to device use case.